# Recovery Volume mounted in `/Volumes` after checking for updates

Tags: hard-drive, recovery

From my understanding, with the new APFS system for macOS, the Recovery volume mounts itself briefly when it checks for updates; however the Recovery Volume on my MacBook Air is still mounted in `/Volumes` after finishing checking for updates:

[image: Recovery Volume mounted]

I could simply unmount the volume as if it were a external USB or restart my computer to unmount it, but I don't know why Recovery is still mounted after it has already checked for updates. Has anyone else experienced anything like this before? What can I do to prevent this in the future?

Comment: @Redarm any insight on this?

Comment: @Nimesh Neema any chance you would know something about this...

Comment: I'm afraid, not.

Comment: @Redarm any assistance/insight would be greatly appreciated as you helped me on my last issue

Comment: I would have already shared an answer if I had one :) Keep watching the space, good luck!

Comment: @NimeshNeema i contacted Apple support and we preformed a full erase of my hard-drive to start fresh; unfortunately this behavior happened once more since then with the strange single occurrence of where in `/Volumes` there was a broken alias for the Recovery Volume that was unable to be interacted with(went away when i restarted)

Comment: @nonope Just for future reference, since Redarm hasn't been part of the communication on this specific question, he won't get pinged when you try using @ to notify them. The @ option only works on a previous commenter for the specific post at hand. It also works for the person posting the question or answer.